# Recursively delete particular directories and files

Tags: c#, .net

I want to delete particular directory in following mainDir.

```
public readonly DirectoryInfo mainDir = new DirectoryInfo("C:\Export\DataFiles\");
```

The mainDir may contain subdirectories and subdirectories may contain more directories...

I only get file name with fullpath.. I want to delete all parents directories of the file (including files), but not the main directory. What is the better way to do it?

Example files:

```
C:\Export\DataFiles\20392\483928\292833\file1.txt
C:\Export\DataFiles\20392\483928\292833\file2.txt
```

Here, I want to delete C:\Export\DataFiles\20392

```
C:\Export\DataFiles\3222\file1.txt
```

Here, I want to delete C:\Export\DataFiles\3222

```
C:\Export\DataFiles\4342\425622\file1.txt
C:\Export\DataFiles\4342\425622\file2.txt
C:\Export\DataFiles\4342\425622\file3.txt
```

Here, I want to delete C:\Export\DataFiles\4342

**EDIT:**

I cannot use following:

```
mainDir.delete(true);
```

It will delete all the directories and files in the mainDir.

Comment: variable mainDir is the main direcotry.

Comment: You just want to remover ALL files and directories from that folder? that sounds easy enough - whats your problem

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you done any research on deleting files from C#?

Comment: It would be the easiest to simply delete this main folder and create it again. But otherwise get all files and subfolders using dir, then delete those. Excluding . and .. obviously. What is the problem?

Comment: @PJvG: I get dynamic file names..

Comment: Maybe you may have a look at [Directory.Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: And https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called "itterating through a directory tree". A fairly simple problem, usually solved via recursion:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx

"Find every entry in the directory. If if it is a directory itself, recurse into it. Then delete the directory. Delete all non-directories (files) you find."

Once you have the full path a file, you can delete it. And that code finds you the full paths of all files and folders in a directory tree.

Comment: Your answer lead me to solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is to use the [Directory.Delete(folder_path, recursive: true)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. This method will delete all sub-directories including the files they contain in a recursive way (if recursive is set to true).

Also, you need to get the right path based on the folder you always want to delete from. For this you can use `Regex` or `String.Split()`. Since the base folder you want to delete from always has the same name, this can be easily achieved by checking on this name after you split the path string.

An implementation I wrote:

```
string folderToSplitOn = "DataFiles";

// Split your input string to detect from which path to delete
string path = @"C:\Export\DataFiles\20392\483928\292833\file1.txt";
string[] splittedString = path.Split('\\');

// Assuming you want to split from DataFiles, loop through your splitted results like this
string pathToDeleteFrom = null;
for (int i = 0; i < splittedString.Length; i++)
{
    pathToDeleteFrom += splittedString[i] + @"\";

    // It's now equal to the folder you want to delete from. Add the extra folder and finish
    if (splittedString[i].Equals(folderToSplitOn))
    {
        pathToDeleteFrom += splittedString[i + 1] + @"\";
        break;
    }
}

// Now you can delete all files and subfolders
Directory.Delete(pathToDeleteFrom, true);
```